# Remove items from a Set that are present in a List - Streams

Tags: java, algorithm, java-stream

I am trying to remove some objects from a Set (HashSet), but only if they are also present into a List (LinkedList).
How can I achieve this with Java 8+ features (streams).

`Set<MyObject> theSet -> want to remove items that are present in the list`

```
List<MyObject> theList
```

I have overriden the equals and hashcode for MyObject (use only a few fields for comparison of equality).

Comment: must it be `Stream`? What about the `removeAll()` method? Check [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: you are right, it should not have been necessarily Stream, however, I did try the removeAll all method, and IntelliJ complained that it may be slow (bcs i was applying it to a Set apparently). Thats why I assumed that the next best choice would be Streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your set is mutable, you could just remove all entries present in your list from the set like so:

```java
theSet.removeAll(theList);
```

Suppose your set is immutable, then you can filter it with a stream resulting in a new set missing the entries present in the list like so:

```java
var newSet = theSet.stream()
    .filter(n -> !theList.contains(n))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

For Java 11+ you could use a method reference for the filter predicate via composition:

```java
var newSet = theSet.stream()
    .filter(Predicate.not(theList::contains))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

### Little note on performance

Both approaches (removeAll and via streams) run in **O(N * M)** where *N* is the size of `theSet` and *M* the size of `theList`. It boils down to two nested for-loops.

An easy enhancement would be to turn `theList` into a set and driving the cost of the linear contains check down to an asymptotic runtime of **O(1)**.

```java
var numsToExclude = new HashSet<>(theList);
var newSet = theSet.stream()
    .filter(Predicate.not(numsToExclude::contains))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the java 8 stream version since thats the language level I am using. With the removeAll way of doing it, IntelliJ complained that it might be slow, so I went with the stream implementation.

Comment: When you have a Set with O(1) lookup, like a `HashSet`, a plain `for(Object o: theList) theSet.remove(o);` will have O(M) whereas your stream operation indeed has O(N * M). The time complexity of `removeAll` depends on the actual implementation. When you’re using the reference implementation and have a list with less elements than the set, the complexity of `removeAll` will be O(M).

Comment: @Holger You mean the upper stream impl? The lower should be in **O(N + M)**.

Comment: Exactly. As you said.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the `removeIf()` method from the `Collection` interface. So you can say something like:

```
theSet.removeIf(theList::contains)
```

It will also return a `boolean` that indicates whether any elements were removed or not.

Comment: Which is definitely worse than `theSet.removeAll(theList)`…

Comment: @Holger, absolutely:)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt a stream is as fast as a simple loop consider the streams overhead. You are always going have to iterate over the entire list so I would do it like so. This presumes the original set is immutable.

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,5,8,9,10);
Set<Integer> set = Set.of(3,4,8,2,1);
Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>(set);
        
for(int val : list) {
     result.remove(val);
}
System.out.println("Before: " + set);
System.out.println("After:  " + result);
```

prints

```
Before: [1, 8, 4, 3, 2]
After:  [3, 4]
```

Since Sets can't hold duplicates, encountering duplicates in the removal list won't affect the outcome.  So if you could gather those in a `Set` rather than a `List` it might offer some improvement.

Finally, your `Object` to be removed must override `equals` and `hashCode` for the above to work.

Comment: Yea, bold exclamation mark on properly overriding equals and hashCode.